# I want to create this nice animation in android studio. Can someone help me?

Tags: android-studio

This is the animation I would like to create:

Thank you in advance.

https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1zX_pOPDo5almLTjUZDu4utGu1hi0MTY-%2Ftype-nav-drag-02.mp4

Comment: You need to try first and come here with a specific question, with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) to implement activity transition animations. The video you've linked seems to be using slide up and slide down for the entry and exit transitions respectively. You can also create your custom transitions and apply them, if those do not exactly match the effects you desire.